# Determining filesystem for block device if module not loaded

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, filesystems, kernel-module

I've been wondering this for a while now. When using Linux and plugging in an e.g. USB stick or external storage device via USB, how does the kernel determine which filesystem is on that device, if the correct module is not currently loaded in memory?

Assume that the external storage device is ext4 formatted. At the time of plugging in the device, the ext4 module has not been loaded into memory yet. Now, usually the kernel tries to probe the different filesystems by calling the appropiate [*_fill_super](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/fs/ext4/super.c#L4005) function of the respective module. But that only works if the module is even present at the time of probing. How does the kernel handle mounting devices in situations where the correct filesystem module is not yet loaded in memory?

For me it seems to be a kind of chicken-egg problem as the *_fill_super function needed to determine the correct module is located in the module itself. So the kernel wants to probe the filesystem on the device, but for that it requires the appropiate module to be loaded. But it is not loaded at that time, so the kernel neither knows what filesystem is on the device and thus does not know what filesystem module to load in the first place.

How does the kernel handle this? I'm thankful for any explanation or even references to the code where this logic happens.

Comment: *"For me it seems to be a kind of chicken-egg problem"* - well not really, it would have been a chicken-egg problem if the kernel had no module and the module was in the USB device :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short: Unless some **user space** configuration file is aware of a filesystem, `mount` will fail to auto-detect this filesystem if its driver is not loaded.

> .. usually the **kernel** tries to probe the different filesystems by calling the appropiate `*_fill_super` function of the respective module.

This is not quite true. The [mount system call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html) accepts filesystem name as a parameter, and this parameter is **required** for all cases except re-mount, which is out of scope of the current question. Moreover, the filesystem driver is expected to be **already loaded** at the time `mount` system call is performed.

That is, the kernel by itself never "probes" a filesystems, the kernel just tries the filesystem requested by the user space.

Actually, it is user space [tool mount](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) which performs probing.

Before probing, the `mount` tool could attempts to **deduce** a filesystem by inspecting `/etc/fstab`, by using `blkid` or other mechanisms.

After all deducing mechanisms have failed, the `mount` tool **probes** filesystems according to `/etc/filesystems` file. This file could contain a **predefined** (static) list of filesystems.

After attempts for every line in `/etc/filesystems` have failed (or if the file doesn't exist), the `mount` tool **probes** filesystems listed in `/proc/filesystems`. This file is provided by the kernel and contains all filesystems which are **registered** (for which a driver is loaded).

After attempts for every line in `/proc/filesystems` have failed, the `mount` tool reports an error.

---

The algorithm of choosing a filesystem by the `mount` tool is described in [man mount](https://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) under the paragraph "If no -t option is given ..". [The question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24189/how-does-linux-keep-track-of-filesystems) and its answers describe similar things.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, this is what I was looking for.